# Set jQuery slider values and send them with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m using the [jQuery](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) slider plugin and trying to achieve the following:

**1.** I want to set different slider `max values` depending on which `li data-value` element the user has clicked.

For example if you click on the `<li data-value="582">` attribute the `max value` of the slider should be **39**. The **39** should get send as the variable `stufe` to the server sided script.

**2.** The default loaded slider value should always be the `max value` of the current clicked `li data-value` element.

For example if you click on the `<li data-value="0">` attribute the default loaded slider value should be **34**. The **34** should get send as the variable `stufe` to the server sided script.

I´ve made a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b9zju4pd/1/) for better understanding, but I´ve the following problems:

- the slider jumps automatically back to the maximum value of the slider, no matter which value you are choosing
- it sends the wrong values to the server sided script (check the developers tools´ network tab)

**This is my try:**

```
    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 1,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    },
    stop: getResponse
});

$("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
getResponse(0);

let $li = $('ul#menu li').on('click', function () {
    // set a class on the clicked element to be able to read its properties later
    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    getResponse();
});

function getResponse() {
    let bonus = parseInt($('ul#menu li.active').attr('data-value'));
    let stufe = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");

console.log(bonus);

  if(isNaN(bonus)) {
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("option", "max", 29);
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", 29);
      $("#amount2").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('option', 'max'));
      $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('value'));
            }
  else if (bonus === 0) {
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("option", "max", 34);
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", 34);
      $("#amount2").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('option', 'max'));
      $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('value'));
            }
  else if (bonus === 582) {
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("option", "max", 39);
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", 39);
      $("#amount2").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('option', 'max'));
      $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('value'));
            }

    ajaxManager.add({
        type: "GET",
        cache: "true",
        url: "itemscript.php",
        data: {
            "bonus": bonus,
            "stufe": stufe
        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
}
});
```

Comment: Why should it send 34? You are telling it to send whatever value user stopped at. Then you are programmatically setting the value to 34 when request completes. The jump is because you set those values in your success code

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense... 29, 34, 39, 0, 582, ... ?

Comment: Why doesn´t the question make sense? Changing the maximum value of a slider depending on the value of a certain variable `(bonus)` makes sense. Anyways. I´ve made some edits to my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe got the result you wanted, see notes inside code.

```
 jQuery(function($) {

  var ajaxManager = $.manageAjax.create('cacheQueue', {
    queue: 'clear',
    cacheResponse: true,
    preventDoubleRequests: true,
    abortOld: true
  });

  // Slider Script

  $("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    },
    stop: getResponse
  });

  $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
  

  myFunction() // slider settings on load

function myFunction(newVal){
    let boo

    if (typeof newVal != 'undefined') { // this is how you properly cheack for undefined
      boo = newVal;
    }else{
     boo = (function () { return; })(); // this is how you make it undefined
    }
    if (typeof boo == 'undefined') {
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("option", "max", 29);
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", 29);
      $("#amount2").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('option', 'max'));
      $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('value'));
    } else if (boo == 0) {
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("option", "max", 34);
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", 34);
      $("#amount2").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('option', 'max'));
      $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('value'));
    } else if (boo == 582) {
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("option", "max", 39);
      $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", 39);
      $("#amount2").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('option', 'max'));
      $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider('value'));
    }
    
    getResponse();  // now call it here so you fetch new initial settings on click and on load
}



  let $li = $('ul#menu li').on('click', function() {
    // set a class on the clicked element to be able to read its properties later
    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    let newVal = $(this).attr('data-value'); // get value of cliked element
    myFunction(newVal) // slider settings on click
  });

  function getResponse() {
    let stufe = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
    let bonus = $('ul#menu li.active').attr('data-value')
    
    
    console.log(bonus)
    console.log(stufe)

    ajaxManager.add({
      type: "GET",
      cache: "true",
      url: "https://elder-scrolls-online.eu/datenbank/itemscript.php",
      data: {
        "bonus": bonus,
        "stufe": stufe
      },
      success: function(data) {

      }
    });
  }
});
```

**Edit:**

Fixed it, this whole way of you trying to change and reset slider inside `getResponse()` was causing a lot of trouble of jquery.Every time that function was called it did something to slider.

So move that settings to new function that will be called just 2 times, on load, and on click. And inside `getResponse()` you just grab values and send them.

https://jsfiddle.net/ikiK_Cro/bzy8v60n/75/

Comment: Thank you. Nearly perfect. If you run the code the first time it sends `stufe=1` instead of `stufe=29` via AJAX. I´ve made the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pf1s386/) for you to see the problem. Rest works prefectly.

Comment: @Berstos Im getting some console errors as well but I just get it why, it should work. looks like script error on jquery part. Im looking into it. And I made slight changes in mid time.

Comment: @Berstos But the problem on first run you are refering to can be easley fixed by moving the  `let stufe = ... `after the all if statements in function: https://jsfiddle.net/ikiK_Cro/bzy8v60n/24/

Comment: @Berstos Can you confirm its working fine in live case? Console error due to slider script is still there.

Comment: Yes, the max values get send correctly. But I noticed that if you choose some other value on the slider nothing gets send via AJAX. But that´s the case in your fiddle, too. For example: move the slider to "10", normally the value `stufe=10` should be sent, but it doesn´t.

Comment: @Berstos Yeah cose of the crashing plug in. See me edit, its fixed.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for all your effort. Now there is just one small mistake. If you run the code the first time it will make two AJAX requests. It sends `stufe=1` and `stufe=29`. But it should just send `stufe=29`. Rest is working perfectly now.

Comment: @Berstos Yeah missed that, you just need to call one function on load the settings one, that one will call response. I forgot to remove the response function initial load, so it was called 2 times. I edited the fiddle and code.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your code:

- in your if chain in **getResponse()** you compare `bonus` strikt to a number (0 or 582) with `===` which would always be `false` because the value from the data-attr is a string, so you have to parse it to a number before that comparison.

Therefor it should be:

```
let bonus = parseInt($('ul#menu li.active').attr('data-value'));
```

Try it in my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/biberman/e9L2nmpx/1/) because i didn't get it to work in a stack snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I´ve taken your first fiddle. If you look under the network tab of the developer tools´ you will see that it sends the wrong `stufe` value to the server sided script. Example: if you click on "Version 0" it sends `stufe=1`, but it should send `stufe=34` (always the max value).I can´t find the mistake.

Comment: Oh, i didn't watch the network tab. Then the answer was rubbish. I changed it to only parsing bonus to a number...

Answer (score 0):

You are reading slider value first then updating it's value later conditionally thus it's picking previously selected value. you have to do it in other way.

You can run below snippet and see the netwotk.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var ajaxManager = $.manageAjax.create('cacheQueue', {
    queue: 'clear',
    cacheResponse: true,
    preventDoubleRequests: true,
    abortOld: true
  });

  // Slider Script

  $("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 1,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    },
    stop: getResponse
  });

  getResponse(0);

  let $li = $('ul#menu li').on('click', function() {
    // set a class on the clicked element to be able to read its properties later
    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    getResponse(parseInt($('ul#menu li.active').attr('data-value')));
  });

  function getResponse(bonus) {
    console.log(bonus);

    let stufe;
    if (isNaN(bonus)) {
      stufe = 29;
    } else if (bonus === 0) {
      stufe = 34;
    } else if (bonus === 582) {
      stufe = 39;
    }

    $("#slider-vertical").slider("option", "max", stufe);
    $("#slider-vertical").slider("value", stufe);
    $("#amount2").val(stufe);
    $("#amount").val(stufe);

    ajaxManager.add({
      type: "GET",
      cache: "true",
      url: "https://elder-scrolls-online.eu/datenbank/itemscript.php",
      data: {
        "bonus": bonus,
        "stufe": stufe
      },
      success: function(data) {

      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header {
  border: 1px solid #444 !important;
  background: none !important;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  cursor: default;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  background-color: #353232;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #817373!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://elder-scrolls-online.eu/datenbank/ajmanager/ajaxmanager.js"></script>
<p>
  <label class="item-slider" for="amount">Stufe:</label>
  <input class="item-slider" readonly id="amount">/
  <input class="item-slider" readonly id="amount2">
</p>

<div id="slider-vertical" style="height:10px;"></div>

<ul id="menu" role="menu">
  <li data-value="0">Version 0</li>
  <li data-value="582" class="ui-menu-item">Version 1</li>
</ul>
```